# Inflection points and the second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

I have a doubt about the classification of a point as an inflection point. I know that if a function $f$ is twice differentiable at $x_0$ and if $x_0$ is an inflection point then $f''(x_0)=0$.

**My question:** the vice-versa holds? I mean when I have a function if I compute the second derivative, then all its zeros are classified as inflection points?

Comment: No. Take $ f(x)=x^4$ and $ x_0=0$.

Comment: So what I should do is checking first of all of the second derivative is $0$, otherwise I can't have an inflection point, but then I have also to check if the sign of the second derivative change at right and left of this point, right?

Comment: what I have just said in my comment!?

Comment: @Nik alternatively you can show it by computing the third derivative, when it's not too hard to do, and if it's non zero you must have an inflection point. Since many times computing the derivative might be easier than checking the sign, it is a possibility not to ignore.

Comment: To detect them from the graph, inflection points are those where the tangent cross the curve.

Comment: @SamueleMonitto thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Essaidi thank you!

Comment: @SamueleMonitto when I compute the first derivative and I have two zeros of it, I have to expect two inflection points?

Comment: @Nik The first derivative has nothing to do with it. When you look for inflection points, you look for a maximum or minimum for $f’$. In general, for a function $g(x)$, there are two ways of finding if it is a maximum(minimum); you take the zeros of $g’$ and you look at how the sign changes around them, or another (only sufficient) condition is that if $g’’(x_0)\neq0$ where $x_0$ is one of the zeros of $g’$, then you have a maximum or minimum. Now, apply this to $g=f’$, then $g’’=f’’’$ and you apply the test. Note that the test is inconclusive if $g’’’(x_0)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia describes an inflection point as follows:

> In particular, in the case of the graph of a function, it is a point where the function changes from being concave (concave downward) to convex (concave upward), or vice versa.

Since we assume the function to be smooth enough we can use the following characterisation of convex/concave: A function $f$ is locally convex at $x$ if $f''(x)> 0$ and locally concave at $x$ if $f''(x)< 0$. So your comment is correct: If the second derivative changes its sign at $x_0,$ it is an inflection point but not vice versa as the counterexample in the comment proves.

**EDIT:** I changed the inequalities to strict inequalities.

Comment: Thanks! So I have also to check if there is a change of sign of the second derivative